# Show a checkbox element only once and below objects in a loop

Tags: html, css, twig

I was able to make all images in a loop except the first 4 hidden in an unfolding element with the code I posted, but I'm struggling making the unfold message display only once and BELOW all elements.
Here is how it looks like before clicking the unfold message:
[image]

Here's how it looks like after clicking on any of those:
[image]

I tried putting `<label for="hd-2">Show remaining images</label>` below the loop, but then CSS styling stops working. Unfortunately, I lack CSS knowledge to keep CSS styles working if I move **label** below the loop (if it's possible at all).

```
### Twig ###

{% block imagelist_field %}
    <div class="imagelist columns">
        {% for image in value %}
        {% if loop.index0 is divisibleby(4) %}
            <input class="hide" id="hd-2" type="checkbox">
            <label for="hd-2">Show remaining images</label>
            <div class="section-imagelist">
        {% endif %}
        {% if value|length < 4 %}
            <div class="below4">
        {% endif %}         
        <div>
            {{ popup(image.filename, 320, 240) }}
        </div>
        {% if loop.index is divisibleby(4) or loop.last %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if value|length < 4 %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

### CSS ###

.hide, .section-imagelist:nth-child(n+4)  {
  display: none;
}

.hide + label {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    }

.hide:checked + label {
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.hide:checked + label ~ * {
    display: flex !important;
}

.hide + label:before {
    background-color: #1e90ff;
    color: #fff;
    content: "\002B";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 3px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 16px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.hide:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2212";
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you get a notification so am commenting, I've undeleted my answer as I think I've worked out a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the checkbox infront of the loop and the label after. You then tweak the CSS so it doesn't rely on the label and checkbox being next to eachother (you actually don't need the relationship selector `+` in the label case).

You can then use the class `.section-imagelist` to show/hide the groups of four images as you need.

**Hide all .section-imagelist by default**

```
.section-imagelist {
  display: none;
}
```

**Show the first one by default**

```
.section-imagelist:first-of-type {
  display: inherit !important;
}
```

**Show all .section-imagelist if they are preceded by a checked element with class .hide**

```
.hide:checked~.section-imagelist {
  display: inherit;
}
```

Let me know if that isn't what you wanted.

---

## Twig

```
{% block imagelist_field %}

    <div class="imagelist columns">

      {# The checkbox can be placed as the first child. It does not need to be adjacent to the label (the for= parameter lets it know which one to change #}
      <input class="hide" id="hd-2" type="checkbox">

      {% for image in value %}

          ...
          ...
          ...

      {% endfor %}

      {# The label should be last, so it is always after the images #}
      <label for="hd-2">Show remaining images</label>

  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

---

```css
img {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.hide:checked~label {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.section-imagelist {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.section-imagelist:first-of-type {
    display: inline-block;
}

.hide:checked~.section-imagelist {
    display: inline-block;
}

label:before {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  color: #fff;
  content: "\002B";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 3px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hide:checked~label:before {
  content: "\2212";
  background: red;
}

label[for='hd-2'] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagelist columns">

  <input class="hide" id="hd-2" type="checkbox">

  <div class="section-imagelist">

    <div>
      <a>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240/09f">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240/09f">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240/09f">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240/09f">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="section-imagelist below4">

    <div>
      <a>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240">
      </a>
    </div>


  </div>

  <label for="hd-2">Show remaining images</label>



</div>
```

Comment: The thing is that all "that logic" is needed for other purposes. It breaks the line after each 4th image. And applies different styles if there are less images than 4. In other words, I need all of that.

Comment: And that's how it starts to look like with your code: http://i65.tinypic.com/1zn0acg.jpg

P.S. I appreciate your help anyway.

Comment: Can you post the html output  of the page (your code)? I should be able to tweak the selectors to match your other work.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use your HTML structure. This works.

Comment: With this, there are a few issues:

1) below4 class stops being applied (I get 4 images per line on all resolutions, even though I have another condition for display max-width 479px);
2) With images unfolded, the layout is broken: http://i64.tinypic.com/24watyx.jpg
3) I can't get to understand how I can apply 'cursor: pointer' to the checkbox, including its text, like it was initially.

Comment: `cursor: pointer` added and the layout has been fixed. I'm not sure what you need with `below4` so I'll leave that to you...

Comment: I fixed below4 issue myself, no problem. But... ugh, sorry, but with your latest edit all images are shown by default.

Comment: That's what I finally came to so it works:

`.section-imagelist:first-of-type {
  display: inherit;
}

.hide:checked~.section-imagelist {
  display: inline-block;
}

.section-imagelist:last-of-type {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}`

P.S. without last-of-type width 100%, images from the last section would be rendered too small. Now I have too large vertical margins between sections, but I suppose I'll shorten them using negative margin-top. I'm accepting your answer because without your help I wouldn't finish this at all.

Comment: Glad you worked it out! Good luck with the rest of the project

Comment: Just an update... Instead of all that, I used `.hide:checked~.section-imagelist {
  display: flex;
}` and everything became perfect instantly without extra code :)

Comment: In order to not show the offer to unfold images if there are less than 4 of them, I had to move label to the loop. Then I added `label:not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
}` to CSS. And finally this is all done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186021/discussion-between-erik-gordon-and-oliver-trampleasure).